# eTrade array parameter with variable inside array

Tags: php, arrays

In the eTrade PHP API they allow the ability to fetch for stocks by symbol. This works when manually typing in the symbols into the array:

```
$request_params->__set('symbolList', array('AAL', 'AAPL', 'AMZN'));
```

What I would like to do is have a variable with the same exact string like:

```
$symbols = "'AAL', 'AAPL', 'AMZN'";
$request_params->__set('symbolList', array($symbols));
```

But this returns nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$symbols = "'AAL', 'AAPL', 'AMZN'";
$request_params->__set('symbolList', explode(', ', $symbols));
```